Unusually Low CPU Time Recorded by Limits.getCPUTime After DML Operation in Platform Event Trigger
I’ve encountered an unusual behavior in Salesforce Apex when working with a Platform Event. Specifically, it seems that Limits.getCPUTime returns an unexpectedly low value after performing a DML operation within the trigger.
Here’s a sample code to demonstrate the issue:
trigger PlatformEventBugTrigger on PlatformEventBug__e (after insert) {
    Integer startTime = Limits.getCPUTime();
    
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        // Simulating some processing
    }
    
    Integer endTime1 = Limits.getCPUTime();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    update accounts;
    
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        // Simulating some processing
    }
    
    Integer endTime2 = Limits.getCPUTime();

    System.debug('start: ' + startTime); // ~20ms
    System.debug('end1: ' + endTime1); // ~45 ms
    System.debug('end2: ' + endTime2); // ~1 ms, which is really low
    System.debug('Time Taken: ' + (endTime1 - startTime));
}

As seen above, the CPU time logged after the DML operation (end2) is significantly lower than expected, even though a similar block of code was executed before the DML operation.
My Questions:

Why does Limits.getCPUTime() return such a low value after the DML operation in the context of a Platform Event trigger?
Is there some internal optimization or behavior in the Salesforce platform that might explain this anomaly?
How can I accurately measure the CPU time consumed by the operations in such a context?

NOTE: I also tried running this code from a flow which was waiting for platform event(User context, which is different form Automated Process User), but still same result

Could you consider capturing the CPU time value immediately after the update accounts; line as well? I'm wondering if there are a couple of different things happening here, including inconsistent optimization of the Apex. If you add another local variable, and an assignment statement in the loops to this variable from the i loop variable, plus include the resulting value (9999) in your System.debug, does that make both loops take similar amounts of time?

Immediately after DML operation, it still displays CPU Limit as 1 or 2 ms, In my code example I added an extra loop just to make sure the processing is taking enough time. Also the for loop is just for simplicity, even with real processing it displays the same result

It sounds like the Limits API value is getting reset after DML, but it also seems (from what you said) that it doesn't then actually track further CPU usage appropriately. I've not noticed this myself and cannot suggest why you see this nor how to resolve it.

After discussion with SF support here is the response I got:

If Duplicate rules are enabled for the object, sf spawns new thread
for checking any duplicate records in background, and resets cpu time
limit

And this behaviour is surprisingly only visible when running in Platform event trigger context.
So technically this piece of code when executed from PE trigger context will keep running for >3mins without hitting CPU time limit and we get a single debug log for the entire operation:
public with sharing class DebugCPUTime {
    public static void execute() {
        for(Integer k = 0; k < 40; k++) {
            for(Integer i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                for(Integer j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    // Simulating some processing
                }
            }
            insert new Account(Name = 'Dummy ' + k); // After each DML the CPU time is reset if duplicate rule is active on account
        }
    }
}



Why does Limits.getCPUTime() return such a low value after the DML operation in the context of a Platform Event trigger?

Loops counting to 10k aren't considered slow any more in Apex. A simple test shows that an empty loop of 10k iterations reports about 96ms wall clock time and 23ms CPU time. CPU time will always be lower by wall clock time, usually substantially, because things like callouts and queries don't count against CPU time. In fact, depending on what the org has for automations, the DML operation itself might cost negligible CPU units measuring in just milliseconds. Also, CPU time is crazy inaccurate. It's literally impossible to predict when the CPU time will be updated (it's not metered every so many instructions, for example), so sometimes even really big loops might report 0 CPU time. Basically... it's practically random (but always in the developer's favor). This is especially true for asynchronous processes, which are granted more flexibility in exchange for actual speed/resources.

Is there some internal optimization or behavior in the Salesforce platform that might explain this anomaly?

Think of CPU time like a billionaire's bank account. They care when they're buying a multimillion dollar jet, but they don't care when they spend five bucks on fast food. That little amount of money that most people watch like a hawk literally doesn't matter to our hypothetical billionaire. CPU time is a lot like that. Yes, the limits are meant to constraint overuse on a shared resource, but it's not that stringent that it counts every last nanosecond for accuracy.

How can I accurately measure the CPU time consumed by the operations in such a context?

Use wall-clock time if you want actual performance. It is always accurate to the nearest millisecond.
Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
doExpensiveThing();
Long endTime = DateTime.now().getTime();

This won't tell you how much CPU time you're using, but you'll have an accurate understanding of how much actual time your process takes, which is usually more important for performance anyways.

Thank you for the response @sfdcfox but same code when running in normal context displays reasonable CPU limit, funny part is if I add few more nested loops the Limits.getCPUTime() still shows 1 or 2 ms but reaches CPU time limit in PE context. I get your point, the Limits.getCPUTime method is not reliable and behave in weird way in async processes
